# TNS No Listener - Only in Visual Studio, DB tool and all pings work

Tags: oracle, listener, tns

**THEN:**
Wednesday before Thanksgiving all works well, all my asp.net C# projects can hit/return data from all the Oracle DBs we use.

**NOW:**
Come in Monday: TNS No Listener every time I run any of our apps. It happens right in page_load where the code goes to the DB to fill some screen controls, happens on the first call.
All other DB tools on my box work fine, we use Benthic Golden for our DB viewer and it hits all the DBs we use. Ping and TNSPing both return an OK. The Oracle 'Net Manager' config tool tests 'good' on the DB instances.

**WHAT I'VE DONE:**
I installed TortoiseSVN (ver 3.?) as well as Visual SVN for Visual Studio (ver 1.79). I have re-installed Oracle 11.1g client (administrative option). We use 32 and 64 bit installing them in that order, making sure the Environment Variable PATH is correct (it is). This morning I re-installed VS 2012 Ultimate and am still getting the error.

**RECENT PC ACTIVITY:**
Our company just switched over from TFS to Subversion for our code repository. I'm thinking last Wednesday I installed the latest versions (we can use) of Tortoise SVN and Visual SVN. Everyone else on my team has the same, we all stay in lock step with each other, no one else is having this issue.

**RESEARCH:**
2 days of research mostly has the issue 180 degrees from mine, VS can hit the DB and all other DB tools cannot. The only hit that hit close in my mind was something about how IIS hits the DB. One post said to change the Application Pool advanced settings: change 'Enable 32-bit Applications' to 'True'. That didn't work.

I wanted to at lease throw this out to StackOverFlow before I hand my hard drive over to the tech's for a rebuild and start from scratch.

**CURRENT TRY/CATCH INNER EXCEPTION:**
System.Exception: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

**SQL Query (TESTDB01):** *SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID AS VALUE, CUSTOMER_NAME AS TEXT FROM CUSTOMERTABLE WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IS NOT NULL*
 ---> System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException.Check(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
   at CsgSystems.DirectNet.Core.CsgSystemsDatabase.GetDataSet(String strSQL, String strInstance)

Comment: It looks like you have two oracle homes, one for 32 bits and the other is 64 bits. You can connect to database from visual studio which is a 32 bit itself so using 32 bit oracle home. That means you tsnames.ora in 32 bits are correct. But the 64-bit one may have some problems.

Comment: We all have 32 & 64 installed and the Environment Path edited accordingly, 32 first. The TNSNames file is the same in both 'C:/Oracle/Network/Admin' folders.

Comment: So you are using %TNS_ADMIN%, then the tsnames.ora should be fine. There are several things are also worth checking. 1. check whether there's a proper gac for Oracle.DataAccess, check out %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\; 2. check the reference of Oracle.DataAccess in you website; 3. open %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[your version]\Config\machine.config to check whether there is a proper "Oracle Data Provider for .NET" in <system.data><DbProviderFactories>.

Comment: Ivenxu: Everything checks out, all looks good. I contacted our support team, I'm going to re-install the Oracle Client after doing a thorough manual uninstall following: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/manual-oracle-uninstall.php . If that doesn't work they'll re-image my HD and I'll start over.

Comment: then good luck! Hope re-install could help.

Comment: Back in the office from holidays. Box rebuilt, loaded Oracle, VS 2012 and still having the same problem. They put all my previous stuff and settings on new load using MS Easy Transfer. I'm having our LAN dept reload my box again but this time NOT load my previous data back on using easy transfer as I think that is loading the problem back on after the reload. Have read some posts about the firewall blocking access and starting up the 'listener'. I'll try all...

Comment: ... continue... I can still hit the Oracle DB using Benthic Golden 6.0. I can also ping and TNSping the DB with success. It is just Visual Studio getting blocked still.

Comment: Hi, it's sad to know that your problem hasn't been resolved yet. I can understand how vex it is. If I were you, I will try debug System.Data.OracleClient. About how to debug, try http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/21/setting-up-visual-studio-2010-to-step-into-microsoft-net-source-code.aspx. It may be not relevant to your problem, but may can give you some ideas.

Comment: Latest News: I had my computer reloaded on Monday (Jan 6) and after a day of re-installing all I need the problem persisted. A few days after that I had my computer reloaded with just Win7 and MS Office and NOT having all my personal stuff brought over with MS Easytransfer. That seemed to do the trick. I am back working with all database connections working well. That was a lot of work!